# undefined reference to `SDL_Init' при линковке с MinGW

Tags: cmake

Указал имя проекта, минимально требуемую версию, далее это

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} C:/OpenGL/SDL2-2.0.3-mingw/include)
link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} C:/OpenGL/SDL2-2.0.3-mingw/lib/x86)
```

собираю командами

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G "Unix Makefiles" "../build"
make
```

далее генерирует билд файлы, компилирует, но на этапе линковки получаю `undefined reference to`SDL_Init'`для всх функций из`SDL`.

Как исправить?

Находил не одну тему с подобными вопросами, там были примеры с "-lsdl" в качестве `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, но тогда выбивает `cannot find -lsdl`

Comment: Линкер не находит саму библиотеку, судя по всему.

Comment: так она лежит по пути C:/OpenGL/SDL2-2.0.3-mingw/lib/x86

Comment: А toolchain об этом по той или иной причине не знает... Наверняка где-то должны выводиться пути для Include-файлов и библиотек, надо смотреть есть ли там ваш каталог. Может формат файла ему неугоден...

Comment: в смысле, где выводиться?

Comment: установил sdl2 в mingw, но теперь при сборке с флагами -lsdlmain -lsdl выбивает : fatal error: winapifamily.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

В `link_libraries` нужно передавать библиотеки, а не путь к ним. Т.е. нужно передавать полный путь к файлу библиотеки.

Comment: @Ni55aN, значит библиотека не та, или она не там. Покажите, что Вы написали. Или сборка у Вас идёт в x86-64, а Вы передаёте x86 библиотеку.

Comment: @Ni55aN, `SDL2.lib` это точно для mingw, а не visual studio? Там не  `SDL2.a` должно быть?

Comment: @Ni55aN, ну если это правильные библитеки, которые отражают архитектуру выходного проекта(x86 или amd64), тогда должно всё работать, т.к. `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` используется правильно. Ещё могу посоветовать посмотреть выходной make файл, может оттуда будет ясно, в чём ошибка

Comment: @Ni55aN, я таких не знаю. Лучше самому разобраться, это гораздо полезнее.

Comment: @Ni55aN, можно на этом сайте создать чат и пригласить меня туда. Не гарантирую доступность, правда, дел у самого хватает

Comment: @Ni55aN, для cmake это должно быть TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} C:\OpenGL\SDL2\i686-w64-mingw32\lib/SDL2.lib C:\OpenGL\SDL2\i686-w64-mingw32\lib/SDL2main.lib)

Comment: но по тому пути лежат `*.a` файлы

Comment: хмм.. что-то меня сбивает с толку, теперь получается, что можно и просто C:/OpenGL/SDL2/lib/x86/SDL2.dll подключить, не трогая i686-w64-mingw32

Comment: Все же, работает только в том случае, если установить sdl в mingw и указать флаги -lsdl2main -lsdl2, а почему не работает, указав только путь к каждой `.lib`?

Comment: @Ni55aN, с этим Вам предстоит разобраться самостоятельно. Что-то Вы делаете не так, но удалённо такие вопросы не решаются. Всё своими руками.

Comment: конечно никто кроме меня этого делать не будет, но в сети нахожу много противоречивых ответов

Comment: @Ni55aN, да не надо ничего искать в сети. У Вас на руках есть компилятор(линкер) и библиотеки, которые в одном случае работают, а в другом нет — работайте с этим, а не пытайтесь искать ответ в сети. В сети его нет, у Вас своя конфигурация.

Comment: пытаюсь, но почти топчусь на месте, в данном случае без cmake собирает, причем так, как надо(не запихивает sdl2.dll в мой exe), а с cmake получается один независимый exe размером в 5 МБ, откуда понять, почему так происходит - непонятно